# Flutter: display photo or image as modal popup

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to find a solution to have in flutter kind of modal dialog coming up, like an overlay widget over the screen.

Use case: I have a user photo shown as small circle avatar image. If the user taps on the photo, a "popup" shall overlay the screen allowing the user to see the full size photo. For example with the package "photo_view package". Any idea how to solve this? I cannot add the photo_view widget directly to the scaffold as it would permanently overlay the screen. I need it only when tapping on the mini icon.

Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `Dialog`, and  `Gesture Detector` or `InkWell` to get onTap function. 
Here's an example:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Image Popup example')
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
        body: CircleAvatar(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async {
              await showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (_) => ImageDialog()
              );
            },
          ),
          radius: 50.0,
          //Photo by Tamas Tuzes-Katai on Unsplash
          backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/tamas.jpg')
        )
    );
  }
}

class ImageDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      child: Container(
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: ExactAssetImage('assets/tamas.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[Circle Avatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEeWl.png)

[Overlay Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZn1e.png)

Comment: What's the advantage of creating a class instead of a simple widget? Normally I create a class when this needs extra functions and widgets but I may be wrong

Comment: In this particular case there is no advantages because we are using it only once and passing no parameters or anything else.

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting image from network

> **To call:**

```
 GestureDetector(
        onTap: () async {
          await showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) => imageDialog('My Image', imageURL, context));
          );
        },
      ),
```

> **Widget:**

```
Widget imageDialog(text, path, context) {
return Dialog(
  // backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  // elevation: 0,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text(
              '$text',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.close_rounded),
              color: Colors.redAccent,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        width: 220,
        height: 200,
        child: Image.network(
          '$path',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);}
```